# Trying to access one cell in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have imported two .csv files as pandas. One panda, df1, looks something like this:

```
projName    projOwner    Data
 proj0     projOwnder0    5
 proj1     projOwnder1    7
 proj2     projOwnder2    8
 proj3     projOwnder3    3
```

The second panda, df2,  looks like this:

```
projName    projOwner    projEmail    projFirstName    projLastName
 proj0     projOwnder0    email0        firstName0      lastName0
 proj1     projOwnder1    email1        firstName1      lastName4
 proj2     projOwnder2    email2        firstName2      lastName5
 proj3     projOwnder3    email3        firstName3      lastName6
```

Basically what I have done is set the index on the df2 to projName. Now I am iterating through the rows of df1 and want to use data from df2 based on df1.

```
df2 = df.set_index("projName")
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    project_name = str(row['projName'])
    firstName = df2.loc[repo_name,'projFirstName']
    lastName = df2.loc[repo_name,'projLasttName']
```

I have done this and it works on some of the rows, but for others it gives me a string of different values in that column. I have tried using .at, .iloc, .loc and have not had success. Can someone help me to see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? Is there a reason you're not simply merging the two dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this that would be much easier would be to use the pandas merge function to merge the dataframes first, then you don't have to reference the data in one dataframe by the data in another - it's all in one place. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'projName':['proj0', 'proj1'],
             'projOwner':['projOwner0','projOwner1'],
             'Data':[5, 7]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'projName':['proj0', 'proj1'],
             'projOwner':['projOwner0','projOwner1'],
             'projEmail':['email0', 'email1']})


df = df1.merge(df2, on=['projName', 'projOwner'])

print(df)

df.set_index('projName')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['projName'])
    print(row['projOwner'])
    print(row['projEmail'])
    print(row['Data'])
```

`df` now looks like this:

```
   Data projName   projOwner projEmail
0     5    proj0  projOwner0    email0
1     7    proj1  projOwner1    email1
```

And looping through the rows and printing the project, project owner, and email, and data gives this:

```
proj0
projOwner0
email0
5
proj1
projOwner1
email1
7
```

Comment: Oh okay! I began by trying to merge the two but I could not get it to work the way I wanted. Let me try this and see if I can get it! Thank you!

Comment: If the projOwner and projName columns are in different orders in the two pandas, it will still merge correctly?

Comment: Merge merges on the value in the column, not in the order. It will find values where projName and projOwner are the same, and merge those rows. So no, order doesn't matter